# Как добавить в unicorn правило-исключение для определенного урл?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Как в настройках unicorn добавить правило-исключение для определенного url ? Дело в том, что я загружаю пользователей на сайт через csv файл, при больших объемах unicorn возвращает ошибку тайм-аута(60 сек.). Можно ли в настройки добавить правило исключение ? если да, то как? если нет, то как лучше сделать? подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### А может, вообще не надо выполнять долгие задачи в процессе запроса?

Тем более на Unicorn, для которого висение в HTTP-запросе отъедает целый воркер-процесс.

Лучше **отгрузите задачу в фон**. Возьмите ActiveJob из Rails 4.2 или новее, или более конкретную реализацию вроде Sidekiq или Que, и используйте запрос только для **запуска** импорта пользователей. А сам импорт выполняйте в отдельном процессе, в котором никаких таймаутов и вообще зависимости от веба или браузера нет.

Comment: изза такой маленькой задачи не хотел подключать это. Я сделал это в отдельном потоке, в `Thread.new` но иногда там ошибка, долгий запрос к бд, коннект не закрывается, и все рухнет. Как избавиться от такой ошибки?

Comment: @Andiskiy вы продолжаете строить костыли вместо нормального решения. Если у вас в этой долгой задаче ещё и опасный код, который может обвалить весь процесс или мешать обрабатывать запросы (а это запросто, если там используется ActiveRecord, т . к. пул соединений к БД общий), тем больше причин вынести задачу в отдельный процесс.

Comment: `Thread.new` опасный?

Comment: @Andiskiy сам по себе нет, но его можно начинить взрывчаткой. Судя по "но иногда там ошибка, долгий запрос к бд, коннект не закрывается, и все рухнет", у вас именно такой случай.